# SQL query for Oracle cloud explorer

Tags: sql, oracle, integration

How to find table name/names from oracle database if you know column name.

I am using Oracle Cloud Explorer.

I tried this query but it did not work:

```
select table_name 
from all_tab_columns 
where column_name = 'PICK_COLUMN';
```

Answer (score 1):

What does it mean - "it did not work"? What does you have in result?

Among other things, you can try to refer to [other system tables](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2094.htm), such as `DBA_TAB_COLUMNS` or `USER_TAB_COLUMNS`.

Comment: Thanks !! It says "No data found for executed query"or throws error that "table or views does not exist". Let me still check from other systems table.

Comment: The error "table or views does not exist" may mean that you don't have privilegies to select from the table. Try execute select with explicit schema. And make sure that you have privilegies.

Comment: Hey no...i could execute correct query...In oracle cloud explorer it takes below.                 select table_name from all_tab_cols where column_name = 'PICK_COLUMN'; n NOT all_tab_columns

Answer (score 0):

You are going in right way.

Just use `upper` or `lower` on both side of comparision, as Oracle object names are case sensitive if they are created with double quotes else they are case insensitive (stored in upper case name). Whenever you query oracle `dictionary views`, always follow this practise.

So you need following query:

```
select table_name from all_tab_columns where upper(column_name) = 'PICK_COLUMN';
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks Tejash!! Let me try with upper or lower